# Вернуть массив строк из функции которая прочитала файл

Tags: c, массивы, типы-данных

Есть функция main() в ней вызывается функция file(file_name) с адресом на файла, который нужно прочитать в массив и вернуть в переменную в  main
(Сижу в ubuntu 13.10 пишу в NetBeans 7.4)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

char *file(const char *config_file) {

    FILE *fp = fopen(config_file, "r");
    char line[1024];
    char *ip_address[1024] = {};
    char ch = getc(fp);
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (ch != EOF) {
        if (ch != '\n') {
            line[index++] = ch;
        } else {
            line[index] = '\0';
            index = 0;
            ip_address[i] = malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof (char));
            strcpy(ip_address[i], line);
            i++;
        }
        ch = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return ip_address;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt = 0, i;
    char *in_fname = NULL;
    char count = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'f':
                in_fname = optarg;
                char *buff = file(in_fname);
                for (count = 0; count < 12; count++) {
                    printf("%s", buff[count]);
                }
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'f') {
                printf("Вы не выбрали файл\n");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Запускать пытаюсь так

```
./app -f 'text.txt'
```

Содержимое файла text.txt просто строки через "\n",
но в main()  я хочу получать их без  "\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Negash](/users/15402/negash)](/users/15402/negash), во первых, возвращать надо не `char *` а `char **` (аналогично параметру argv[] в main),

во вторых, память под возвращаемый массив указателей надо тоже выделять malloc-ом,

а в третьих, читать строки и урезать `'\n'` IMHO удобней так

```
char **ip_address = malloc(sizeof(*ip_address) * (LIMIT + 1));
char str[LINE_MAX];

while (i < LIMIT && fgets(str, sizeof(str), infile)) {
   int l = strlen(str);
   str[l > 0 ? l - 1 : l] = 0;
   ip_address[i++] = strdup(str);
}
ip_address[i] = 0; // так можно будет узнать размер этого массива
... места мало...
```

**UPD**

Решил преобразовать в ответ и немного дополнить. В Линуке (GNU) есть хорошая функция -- `getline()`. С ней функция чтения строк становится получше.

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out filelines.c
test get_filelines(filelines.c)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define START_INCR 64
#define LIMIT_INCR 1024

char **
get_filelines (const char *filename)
{
  FILE *in = filename ? fopen(filename, "r") : stdin;
  if (!in) // can't open (see errno)
    return 0;
  char **res = 0, *str = 0;
  size_t rsx = 0, capacity = 0, incr = START_INCR, strsz, i;
  ssize_t lstr;

  while ((lstr = getline(&str, &strsz, in)) >= 0) {
    if (rsx + 2 > capacity) { 
      // increase res[] if need it
      if (!(res = (typeof(res))realloc(res, (capacity += incr) * sizeof(*res))))
        return 0; // no memory (see errno)
      if ((incr <<= 1) > LIMIT_INCR)
        incr = LIMIT_INCR;
    }
    if (lstr)
      str[lstr - 1] = 0; // del '\n'
    res[rsx++] = str;
    str = 0;
  }

  if (in != stdin)
    fclose(in);
  if (res) { 
    res[rsx++] = 0; // terminate lines list by NULL
    res = (char **)realloc(res, rsx * sizeof(*res));
  } else {
    errno = 0; // empty file
  }

  return res;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  printf ("test get_filelines(%s)\n", av[1] ? av[1] : "stdin");
  char **flines = get_filelines(av[1]);

  if (!flines)
    perror("get_filelines");
  else 
    while (*flines) 
      puts(*flines++);

  return !flines;
}
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Это она файл со своим кодом печатает.